# how to compare two mysqli_fetch_assoc values using two while loops

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code...

```
while ($guest_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_guest_orders)) {
                                $temp_guest_prod=$guest_orders['prodCode'];
                                $temp_guest_qty=$guest_orders['qty'];
                                while ($logged_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logged_orders)) {
                                    $temp_logged_prod=$logged_orders['prodCode'];
                                    echo $temp_guest_prod."<br />";
                                    if($temp_guest_prod==$temp_logged_prod){
                                        echo "same product<br />";
                                    }
                                    echo "logged prod code: ".$logged_orders['prodCode']."   QUANTITY: ".$logged_orders['qty']."<br />";
                                }
                                $logged_orders="";
                                echo "temp prod code: ".$temp_guest_prod."   QUANTITY: ".$temp_guest_qty."<br />";
                                echo "guest prod code: ".$guest_orders['prodCode']."   QUANTITY: ".$guest_orders['qty']."<br />";
                            }
```

Here is the output...

[image]

I am just a bit confused how this happen. I need to compare two fields to know if they have the same values. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's stick only with 'prodCode'. If you transpose each 'prodCode' column from each table, then you obtain 2 arrays: `$guest_orders_prodCode = array('rhino', 'xxx', 'Shona');`and `$logged_orders_prodCode = array('rhino', 'Shona', 'xxx');`, where `xxx`means no value. Can you now please explain a little better what you want to make with them? Put them one under another to have a better picture.

Comment: This is the scenario, I have a shopping cart that caters all customers regardless if they are logged in or not. If they try to bought a product though they're not logged in, they will be treated as guest which I assign them a unique ID and save them in tblcart with the current date when they bought. Then if they decided to logged in, their orders as guest and as logged in person will be merged. I'm having trouble doing that.

Comment: What do you mean with "will be merged"? Let's say, we just speak about one person (customer): He orders products as guest. They are saved as records in `guest_orders` table. Later he comes again, logges in and makes a new order. These bought products are then saved in `logged_orders` table. Right? Now, you want to take all saved records (products) from `guest_orders` and the ones  from `logged_orders` and you want to do what with them? Do you want to bring them in a third table?

Comment: i only have 2 tables, tblcart and tbltransaction... by the way, the logic of this is similar to lazada.com.ph

when a customer view the site and decided to buy a product but is not yet logged in, that customer's order will be placed in tblcart with a unique customerID I generated using session and uniqid(). if the customer decided then to logged in, his product bought that same session time as guest will be consider as his order and if he has an existing orders, his new orders as guest will just be added

Comment: tblCart for guest products and tblTransaction for logged customers products, right?

Comment: no, tblCart for both of them... the products will only be passed to tblTransaction if the customer proceeds on the payment

Comment: Something doesn't fit in my picture. So, you use one table `tblCart` for guest and logged-in products of a customer. Can we totally ignore your `tblTransaction` from the problem?

Comment: Do you want to loop through the already bought records (of one user) in `tblCart` and to compare them with other products - which weren't yet saved, but should be now saved in tblCart - under a certain condition of equality?

Comment: Great, that's what matters ;-) Your question code and your answer code are both correct, unless I'm missing something. So I would have reformulated the question to "_Can someone explain to me, if this is the correct way?_". Or: "_Is there a better way of doing this?_". You know what I mean? Your answer version is the better one, when you are dealing with database records. It's good to isolate fetching of data from other later operations on it. Good luck and +1 from me for a good answer code!

Comment: @aendeerei, thanks for such an inspirational comment and for your help and also for +1... it's good that there's someone here like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your quick response and kind help. But I already knew the problem now and got a successful answer to it. Below is my solution.

```
while ($guest_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_guest_orders)) {
                                $temp_guest_prod[]=$guest_orders;
                            }

                            while ($logged_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logged_orders)) {
                                $temp_logged_prod[]=$logged_orders;
                            }

                            foreach($temp_guest_prod as $guest_orders) {
                                foreach($temp_logged_prod as $logged_orders) {
                                    if ($guest_orders['prodCode'] == $logged_orders['prodCode']){
                                        echo "guest prod code: ".$guest_orders['prodCode']."   QUANTITY: ".$guest_orders['qty']."<br />";
                                        echo "logged user prod code: ".$logged_orders['prodCode']."   QUANTITY: ".$logged_orders['qty']."<br />";
                                    }

                                }

                            }
```

Still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
while ($guest_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_guest_orders)) {

  $temp_guest_prod=$guest_orders['prodCode'];
  $temp_guest_qty=$guest_orders['qty'];

  echo "Begin ".$temp_guest_prod." comparing :";

  while ($logged_orders=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logged_orders)) {

    $temp_logged_prod=$logged_orders['prodCode'];
    $temp_logged_prod_qty=$logged_orders['qty'];
    echo "Comparing ".$temp_guest_prod." to ".$temp_logged_prod.":<br />";
    //You can also compare name and quantity:
    //if(($temp_guest_prod==$temp_logged_prod) && ($temp_guest_qty==$temp_logged_prod_qty)){ run code... }
    if($temp_guest_prod==$temp_logged_prod){
      echo "Same product<br />"; 
      $logged="YES"; 
      } else { 
      "Not the same<br />"; 
      }

    echo "logged prod code: ".$temp_logged_prod."   QUANTITY: ".$temp_logged_prod_qty."<br />";
   }

    $logged="";

    echo "temp prod code: ".$temp_guest_prod."   QUANTITY: ".$temp_guest_qty."<br />";
    echo "guest prod code: ".$guest_orders['prodCode']."   QUANTITY: ".$guest_orders['qty']."<br />";

    echo "End of product ".$temp_guest_prod." comparing. <br /> Result:";

    if($logged=="YES"){
      echo "Match found!<br /><br />";
      } else { 
      echo "No match.<br /><br />";
      }
}
```

Comment: hi! I tried this. however the next row of $logged_orders are not being compared to the $guest_orders

Comment: This is the scenario, I have a shopping cart that caters all customers regardless if they are logged in or not. If they try to bought a product though they're not logged in, they will be treated as guest which I assign them a unique ID and save them in tblcart with the current date when they bought. Then if they decided to logged in, their orders as guest and as logged in person will be merged. I'm having trouble doing that.

Comment: Oh ok, change $logged for $logged_product. The task of $logged is not to check if the user is logged, it is just to register that a match has been found.

Comment: I just noticed, while I'm testing your code, the 1st whole cycle of the inner while loop is ok and checked, however, when the outer loop increments or step up, the inner loop doesn't cycled.